# Looking for a hint on showing that $|c + \sqrt{c^2 - 1}| \geq 1$ whenever $\mathrm{Re}(c) > 0, c \in \mathbb{C}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I have to show that $|c + \sqrt{c^2 - 1}| \geq 1$ whenever $\mathrm{Re}(c) > 0, c \in \mathbb{C}$, with equality holding only when $c \in (0, 1]$. The problem provides a hint that I should first check that $\mathrm{Re}(\bar{c}\sqrt{c^2 - 1}) \geq 0$, however I don't know how to argue about it other than $\mathrm{Re}(c) > 0$ is equivalent with $\mathrm{Re}(\bar{c}) > 0$, and (I guess?) the real part of a complex square root is non-negative. If we accept the previous argument, then all of the real parts of the summands in $|c + \sqrt{c^2 - 1}|^2$ are non-negative. However I don't know how this helps concluding that the inequality holds for $1$ in the RHS.

Comment: If $c=2$, then $\operatorname{Re}(c)=2>0$, but $\left|2-\sqrt{2^2-1}\right|=2-\sqrt3\approx0.27$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Sorry for the inconvenience, my plus sign was flipped to minus...